# SQL - After insert Same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I understand recursive triggers. Got to be careful of deadlocks etc. However this is only after an insert not after insert and update. Also, I have an audit trigger table that I am updating to make sure all is well. And querying after to double check. All looks fine but no update happens.

```
if exists (select 'a' from sys.triggers where name  = 'invoicememologic')
begin
    drop trigger invoicememologic
end
go

create trigger invoicememologic 
on transactiontable
after insert 
as
begin
    declare @inum varchar(1000)

    select @inum = min(transactioninvnum) 
    from 
        (select transactioninvnum 
         from inserted i 
         inner join project p on left(i.projectid, charindex(':', i.projectid)) = p.projectid  
         where right(i.projectid, 1) <> ':' 
           and abs(p.UseProjectMemoOnInv) = 1 
         group by transactioninvnum) b

    while @inum is not null
    begin
        declare @rCount  int

        select @rCount = count(*) 
        from transactiontable 
        where TransactionInvNum = @inum

        if @rCount = 1 
        begin
            declare @tid varchar(100)

            select @tid = transactionid 
            from transactiontable 
            where TransactionInvNum = @inum

            declare @pmemo varchar(MAX)

            select @pmemo = p.projectMemo
            from transactiontable tt  
            inner join project p on left(tt.projectid, charindex(':', tt.projectid)) = p.projectid 
            where transactionInvNum = @inum

            insert into audittrigger 
            values (@pmemo, @tid)

            update transactiontable 
            set transactionmemo2 = @pmemo 
            where ltrim(rtrim(transactionid)) = ltrim(rtrim(@tid))
        end

        select @inum = min(transactioninvnum) 
        from 
            (select transactioninvnum 
             from inserted i 
             inner join project p on left(i.projectid, charindex(':', i.projectid)) = p.projectid  
             where abs(transactionjointinv) = 1 
               and right(i.projectid, 1) <> ':'  
               and abs(p.UseProjectMemoOnInv) = 1   
             group by transactioninvnum ) a 
        where transactioninvnum > @inum
    end
end
```

Reason for trigger. 1 Invoice can be multiple rows in the database. 3 rows. So it only should update any one of the 3 rows. Doesn't matter. And it must grab the memo from the parent project of the phases that are being inserted into the database. hence the inner join on the left with charindex.

So I check the audit table. All looks well there. MEMO is there and the transactionid is there. I query after the trigger fires. TransactionID exists in the transactiontable but the memo2 is not being updated.

TransactionMemo2 is type of `ntext`. I thought it might be `varchar` with a direct update command will fail. I tried to update manually through setting a var as the text string and call the update manually with the transactionid being required. all worked fine.  I am lost

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Can't do anything about it. This is developed by a completely different company. Just simply trying to add our own custom logic.. HOWEVER I found the problem. The Application is dumb. It does an insert. Then runs an update. Which overrides. So my updates are happening. But it is overriding and setting to 0. So I need 2 seperate triggers. One on insert. 2 on update and use a seperate table as a jobs table. to update the transactiontable.